# Calling a method of a form inside another form

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

Inside my main Form:
`partial class Form1 : Form`

I have this method:
`public void SendLog();`

Inside another class: `class Player`

I have a method which I want to call that `SendLog()` from `Form1`

```
public void Print()
{
    Form1.SendLog();   // Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.SendLog(string)'  
}
```

How do I do that ? My `Player` class contains many calls to `SendLog()` so I prefer to have a global instance of `Form1` declared in the beginning so that I can use something like `f.SendLog();` rather than passing `Form1` instance to method every call.

Like this:

```
class Player
{
    public Form1 f = Form1;
    public void Print()
    {
        f.SendLog();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it does, but then that code must be put inside every method that calls SendLog(). Is there any way I can declare a global reference using that code ?

Comment: Sure, if there is is at any time exacty one instance of `Form1` (this is called a singleton), add a `public static Form1 Instance { get; }` to the `Form1` class and initialize it in the Form1 constructor. Then you can call it from everywhere as `Form1.Instance.Whatever();`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One method is that send the `Form1` class as a parameter to the player class.

Like the following:

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
   
   //...................
   Player player = new Player(this);
   player.Show();
}
```

*Player Class*

```
class Player
{

    Form1 f;
    public Player(Form1 _f)
    {
       f = _f;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        f.SendLog();
    }
}
```

Another way is to use `Application.OpenForms` which Gets a collection of open forms owned by the application.

```
var form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Where(x => x.Name == "formName").FirstOrDefault();
form1.SendLog();
```

or use

```
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if(frm.Name == "formName")
    {
       frm.SendLog();
       break;
    }
}
```